# How to extract data from web services through Linux curl command and then convert it to flat file?

Tags: curl

I want to extract data from web services through cURL command and then want to convert it to flat file. Can someone please help me this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Lucifer - can you show us what you've already tried, and where you are running into problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
curl -o target/path/filename URL >file.extension
```

Comment: I'll check on this. Can you tell me how to convert it into flat file then?

Comment: @Lucifer curl URL  >file.txt (format may be variable, depends on what file format is sent by API)

Comment: Okay.. Thank a lot :)